# transforming a file one character at a time using nodejs streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

I am trying to transform a file character-by-character (as chunks), and during this transformation, some internal state may be composed of these provided chunks.

I implemented this using a readable file stream with a highWaterMark of 1, then piping it through a transform stream which pipes the transformed result to a target file. Below is my code:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const Transform = require("stream").Transform;

const src = "the path of the source file";
const target = "the target path of the resulting file";

// make sure that the directory of `target` exists
ensureDir(target);

const targetStream = fs.createWriteStream(target);

const srcStream = fs.createReadStream(src, { highWaterMark: 1 });

const transformStream = new Transform({
    transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        // do some transformation and call `this.push` or mabye not
        callback();
    },

    flush(callback) {
        // flush the leftover internal state
        callback();
    }
});

srcStream.pipe(transformStream).pipe(targetStream);
```

But as [mscdex](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8855#issuecomment-250635280) states:

> highWaterMark is just an indicator to communicate to upstream that no more data should be written/pushed. Obviously you can write more data and it will just continue to be buffered in memory. highWaterMark does not dictate the size of chunks passed to _transform()/_write().

So, is there a risk that I will get more than one char in some of the chunks that will be transformed?
if yes, how can I be sure that I will get only one at a time?

Comment: What you're asking to do doesn't really make any sense.  Can you explain why you feel you want to handle 1 byte at a time?

Comment: I am just starting to learn node  , so I'm actually just curious about it , and also trying to understand how backpressure works.

Comment: read this - "highWaterMark is a threshold, not a limit". Also, it seems you apply it to readable stream, so it doesn't affect your writeable stream. https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html